# Opening a Quickly dialog using a button

Tags: python, canonical-quickly

I have created a window using quickly add dialog. But I can't figure out how to simply open the dialog from a button. I have already set up a button in my main window and set up the code for it. This is the code for the button:

```
def on_quicksitesbutton_clicked(self, widget):
dialog = QuicksitesDialog.QuicksitesDialog()
result = dialog.run()
```

I also imported the dialog with this line of code:

```
from brandsonicweb.QuicksitesDialog import QuicksitesDialog
```

The program runs fine, but when I click the button I get in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brandon/brandsonicweb/brandsonicweb/BrandsonicwebWindow.py", line 71, in on_quicksitesbutton_clicked
    dialog = QuicksitesDialog.QuicksitesDialog()
AttributeError: type object 'QuicksitesDialog' has no attribute 'QuicksitesDialog'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work?

Comment: you indenting is off in your example, is it like that in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Either write this in the function:

```
dialog = QuicksitesDialog()
```

Or import like that:

```
from brandsonicweb import QuicksitesDialog
```

In your code you finally get this:

```
dialog = brandsonicweb.QuicksitesDialog.QuicksitesDialog.QuicksitesDialog()
```

which is a little too much.